# Polynomial approximation of continuous function on $[0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, weierstrass-approximation

I'm trying to prove that given a continuous function $f:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$, then it can be approximated uniformly on its domain by functions of the form $P(e^{-x})$, where $P$ is a polynomial.

So far i have used the Weierstrass approximation theorem to show that for every $0<r<1$ and for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a polynomial $P$ such that $|f(x)-P(e^{-x})|<\epsilon$ for every $x\in [r,1]$ and with this i have formed a sequence $(P_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $|f(x)-P_n(e^{-x})|<1/n$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Any suggestions on how to go forward?

Comment: You can try to approximate $g(x)=f(-\log x)$, $x\in (0, 1]$, $g(0) =\alpha$ uniformly by polynomials. This $g$ is continuous on $[0, 1]$. Then rephrase it in terms of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = 0$ then it is possible to approximate it by a subalgebra since $[0,\infty)$ is locally compact.
[image]

Taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem

The same argument works even if $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = b$ for some constant $b < \infty$.

Comment: I think the simple Weierstrass theorem works here. See my comment above.

Comment: The problem is Weierstrass theorem works only for compact sets but in your case its $(0,1]$ which is not compact. but if you want to assign $g(0)  = \alpha$ then you need $f(x)$ to converge as $x \rightarrow \infty$ which is what i am saying.

Comment: But that convergence of $f$ is assumed in the problem. Read the question again.

Comment: Oh I see.. Thanks Gary ! In that case you are correct. I kind of stated a more general result. +1 for your comment.